# error after url decoding and post data

Tags: php, asp.net, post, web, postman

After url decoing with postman and send parameters to the url , can not get any result.I think request verification token is needed.
[url and post's parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSpHV.jpg)

When post this parameters to web url can not get any response.
How to solve it?

Comment: post some code to understand

Comment: PLZ open image url

Comment: that's output not code.

Comment: i know , but i want to know: how to add token for post data?

Answer (score 0):

If your token needs to sent via request body you can set the json object with the key name to your token name and value in postman or if your token needs to be send via header you can set this in headers section of postman.